# Filter dict items using list of keys

Tags: vimscript, dictionary, list

Give the following dictionary:

```
let mydict = {'foo': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'bar': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
```

And a list of keys:

```
let myfilter = ['foo', 'asdf']
```

How would one do a **concise** "left outer join (if null)" or filter and remove any items in `mydict` with key in `myfilter`?

"Long" version as a loop:

```
for key in myfilter
    if has_key(mydict, key)
        call remove(mydict, key)
    endif
endfor
```

Which would yield:

```
:echo mydict
{'bar': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
```

It seems some combination of `filter({expr1}, {expr2})` should do the trick, but haven't been able to come up with a `{expr2}` that uses `v:key` and successfully returns 0 when defined in `myfilter` and otherwise silently errs/return something other than 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use `index({list}, {expr} ..)` for this:

```
let mydict = {'foo': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'bar': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
let myfilter = ['foo', 'asdf']

call filter(mydict, 'index(myfilter, v:key) == -1')
```

`index()` returns -1 when `{expr}` is not found in `{list}` and otherwise the lowest index in `{list}`.

```
:echo index(['foo'], 'foo') == -1
0
```

`filter()` removes the item from the List when result of `{expr2}` evaluates to 0.

---

It's also possible to do something similar with dict keys as filter for another dict, but by using `has_key({dict}, {key})`:

```
let mydict = {'foo': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'bar': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
let myfilter = {'foo': '5', 'asdf': '6'}

call filter(mydict, '!has_key(myfilter, v:key)')
```

`has_key()` returns 1 if `{dict}` has an entry with key `{key}`, zero otherwise.

Comment: I believe you can simplify the latter version to: `call filter(mydict, '!has_key(myfilter, v:key)')`.

Comment: You can indeed @KarlYngveLervåg, thanks! Nice seeing you around by the way, had great use for LaTeX-Box back during my studies :)

Comment: Good to hear! (Although you should check out [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/) now, if you still work with LaTeX.)

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I've saved it for the future and it looks pretty sweet, but not much LaTeX these days I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to follow the destructive `remove()` path, you could also execute the following convoluted expression:

```
echo map(copy(myfilter), 'has_key(mydict, v:val) ? remove(mydict, v:val) : mydict')[0]
```

It may be faster with big dictionaries and small list of keys, but honestly, @timss' solution based on `filter()` + `index()` is the way to go. Both solutions will be much faster than any `:for` based solution.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if using `filter()` + `index()` was the way to go and felt a bit hacky, but I found no other answer to my question when searching online. 

Your solution is pretty cool too, and logically "closer" to something I'd originally figure one would do; remove by comparing vals of `myfilter` rather than some function on the `myfilter` list itself. Nice alternative though!

Comment: Well, I find it very hacky as well. I say _"this is the way to go"_ because it does the job well, and because in my [experiments](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/list.vim), `index()` is the fastest around for this kind of jobs.

Comment: I'm curious: Is `index()` faster than `has_key()`?

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg There are not exactly comparable as you'd need to convert the reference elements either from a dictionary to list of keys (`keys(dict)`), or from list to a dictionary (`map(copy(list), extend(dict, {v:val: 1}))`. Whether we'd use one or the other would really depends on the type of the original data. When we have the choice, I suspect `has_key()` to be faster on big collection of data. I'm not sure I had ever benchmarked one against the other, except to answer this question on collections of two elements. And here it's not just `has_key()`. It's `has_key()` + `remove()`.

Comment: I meant as a response to "@timss' solution based on filter() + index() is the way to go.". Would not `filter()` + `has_key()` be better?

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, which `has_key()` solution are you referring to? I've benchmarked mine on the inputs given in the question. With 2 elements to search among two, my solution was slower. It's probably faster on bigger lists, but honestly, I find it convoluted. That's why I prefer `filter()` + `index()`. We would need to test it on real things like tag list or quickfix list.

Comment: For anyone curious my use case was to filter plugins managed by vim-plug and its `g:plugs` dictionary. In other words usually not too many entries, maybe 5-30 or something for most people. https://github.com/timss/vimconf/commit/1b4f629fa6862bbd088d2bad72a40814815860bf (if you see something weird about the rest of the code feel free to comment that as well!)